# Run javaEE from netbeans locally

Tags: jsf, netbeans, glassfish, icefaces

I am trying to run my javaEE site locally in Netbeans IDE. I believe I have everything set up correctly, but I am receiving the following error:

> Initializing... deploy?DEFAULT=C:\Documents and
>   Settings\nicholasr\Desktop\Work Notes\temp code
>   files\ASP\build\web&name=ASP&force=true **failed on GlassFish Server 3.1
>   Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app
>   [ASP] : Servlet [Resource Servlet] and Servlet [Persistent Faces
>   Servlet] have the same url pattern: [/xmlhttp/*].** Please see
>   server.log for more details. C:\Documents and
>   Settings\nicholasr\Desktop\Work Notes\temp code
>   files\ASP\nbproject\build-impl.xml:871:  The module has not been
>   deployed.     at
>   org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:187)
>     at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.ant.Deploy.execute(Deploy.java:106)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:291)
>     at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor62.invoke(Unknown Source)     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:390)  at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:411)     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1399)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1368)    at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
>     at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1251)   at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.bridge.impl.BridgeImpl.run(BridgeImpl.java:284)
>     at
>   org.apache.tools.ant.module.run.TargetExecutor.run(TargetExecutor.java:539)
>     at
>   org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:154)
>   BUILD FAILED (total time: 58 seconds)

I've done some searching on the net, but don't see any related links. Does anyone know why I would be getting this error and how it can be resolved? I can provide any additional information if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Error occurred during deployment: Exception while deploying the app [ASP] : Servlet [Resource Servlet] and Servlet [Persistent Faces Servlet] have the same url pattern: [/xmlhttp/*]*

You seem to be using [IceFaces](http://icefaces.org). I don't do IceFaces, but the error message suggests that they shouldn't be mapped on the very same URL pattern. I did some minor research and based on the following documents...

- [Adding IceFaces 2 to your application](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Adding+ICEfaces+to+Your+Application)
- [Converting IceFaces 1.8 to IceFaces 2](http://wiki.icefaces.org/display/ICE/Converting+ICEfaces+1.8+Applications+to+ICEfaces+2)

  > The previously declared Persistent Faces Servlet and Blocking Servlet are no longer needed in ICEfaces 2, as their functionality has changed and setup has been reduced. Remove all declarations and mappings for those two servlets:

... I can only conclude that the "Persistent Faces Servlet" is typical for IceFaces 1.8.x and the "Resource Servlet" is typical for IceFaces 2.x. You should use the one or the other, not both. I think you're targeting IceFaces 2.x, so you should get rid of the declaration and the mapping of the "Persistent Faces Servlet" in your `web.xml` altogether.

Comment: Ah yeah, I just found it in web.xml like you said. I am using ICEfaaces 1.8.x however, so I just got rid of the "Resource Servlet". Now I got a new error :D

Comment: You're welcome. As to the new question/problem, just press `Ask Question` button on the right top whenever you have a new question/problem and you're stuck with it. Hint: that class is missing in the classpath (but you obviously don't need it, didn't you forgot to remove its `<server>` entry?)

Comment: I don't need it? I'm pretty sure I do

Comment: What is your webapp using then? IceFaces 1.8 or IceFaces 2.0?

Comment: 1.8 per my first comment :) don't really see why this is happening. i have it set up like this link says http://www.icefaces.org/docs/v1_5/htmlguide/gettingstarted/TimezoneTutorial11.html

Comment: Hm, didn't you edit or delete a comment? I'm pretty certain I saw another comment about a `ClassNotFoundException`? Okay as you after all need this class, then that can only mean that the IceFaces 1.8 libraries are missing in `/WEB-INF/lib`. Are you sure that you didn't accidently drop IceFaces 2.x libraries in there as the "Resource Servlet" was apparently correctly initialized?

Comment: @BalusC let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2745/discussion-between-shredder-and-balusc)